# How to get values of a config file which is autoloaded in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter, i want to auto load the email config file and use in my controllers, libraries.

I added email config to *config/autoload.php*

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
...some code ...
*/
$autoload['libraries'] = array(
  'database',
  'session',
  'locale',
  'util/ScriptLoader',
  'activity/Message',
  'Auth_lib',
  'email'
);
```

my *config/email.php*

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
...some code ...
*/
$config['useragent']       = "CodeIgniter";
$config['mailpath']        = "/usr/bin/sendmail"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
$config['protocol']        = "mail";
$config['smtp_host']       = "localhost";
$config['smtp_user']       = "";
$config['smtp_pass']       = "";
$config['smtp_port']       = "25";
$config['system_email']    = "noreply@xxxx.com";
$config['help_email']      = "help@xxxxx.com";
$config['inquiries_email'] = "inquiries@xxxx.com";
$config['support_email']   = "support@xxxx.com";
```

i tried to get `support_email` value in my controller using

```
$this->config->item('support_email')
```

but not working, how to get the auto-loaded values in controller? please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to autoload config files under: `$autoload['config'] = 'email';`

Answer (score 3):

If you dont require to autoload it,

```
1) Place the email.php under application/config
2) In your controller

   $this->config->load('email');
   $this->config->item('support_email')
```